# Where is Content block for <reference name="content" tag

Tags: layout, magento-1, blocks, custom-block

if I use a layout such as:

```
<layout>
   <{handle}>
       <reference name="content">
          ... {blocks} ...
```

According to [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-4.html) and [tutorial](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/)
the reference's name attribute points to referencing an existing block so I'm just wondering where is the `content` block defined?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the regular frontend pages the `content` block is defined in the `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml`:

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
    ...
        <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
            <label>Main Content Area</label>
        </block>
    ...
```

for the adminhtml pages it is defined in the `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml`

```
<default>
    <block type="adminhtml/page" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page.phtml">
    ...
        <block type="core/text_list" name="left" as="left"/>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content"/>
        <block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>
    ...
```

**Note:** For those who using enterprise theme package take a look at the `app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/layout/page.xml` file (in the enterprise package)

Comment: OK cool this is for frontend - what about backend? I'm on magento enterprise

Comment: @gvanto I've updated my answer.

Comment: legendary thank you

Answer (score 1):

`<reference name="content">` Its a **Structural block** of type `core/text_list`, this structural block will automatically render all its children without the need to call the `getChildHtml()`, as like also `<reference name="left">`, `<reference name="right">`

This block is declared in `xml` as like this:
`<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content">`